# StructureMap - Application wide singleton (using Registries)

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, structuremap

In a bigger project we use structure map with multiple Registries - each in a different library (which all are scanned with the `LookForRegistries()` method).

Some of those registries use a special class that should be created as a singleton:

```
public class Registry1 : Registry
{
    public Registry1 ()
    {
        this.For<ISpecialThing>().Use<SpecialThing>().Singleton();
    }
}

public class Registry2 : Registry
{
    public Registry2 ()
    {
        this.For<ISpecialThing>().Use<SpecialThing>().Singleton();
    }
}
```

In the above example, the `SpecialThing` class is instantiated twice.

Is there any way to tell structure map in the registries, to instantiate it only once within our Process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure Map is behaving as expected.

The problem was that the different libararies were imported in their own `Container`, so they were not able to figure out that another container already had a singleton for the interface.

Also, I provide my test solution if anyone has similar problems:

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/458761/StructureMapTest.zip